# How to access the fields of a timeval structure

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to print the values in a `struct timeval` variable as follows:

```
int main()  
{  

    struct timeval *cur;  
    do_gettimeofday(cur);  
    printf("Here is the time of day: %ld %ld", cur.tv_sec, cur.tv_usec);  

    return 0;  
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
request for member 'tv_sec' in something not a structure or union.  
request for member 'tv_usec' in something not a structure or union.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a reason to use `do_gettimeofday` instead of the portable POSIX `gettimeofday`?

Answer (score 7):

Because `cur` is a pointer. Use

```
struct timeval cur;
do_gettimeofday(&cur);
```

In Linux, `do_gettimeofday()` requires that the user pre-allocate the space. Do NOT just pass a pointer that is not pointing to anything! You could use `malloc()`, but your best bet is just to pass the address of something on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the -> operator rather than then . operator when accessing the fields. Like so: `cur->tv_sec`.

Also you need to have the timeval structure allocated. At the moment you are passing a random pointer to the function gettimeofday().

```
struct timeval cur;
gettimeofday(&cur);
printf("%ld.%ld", cur.tv_sec, cur.tv_nsec);
```

Comment: If cur is on the stack, then it is not a pointer. Can't use -> operator then.

Comment: Ok I just tried that, I got any error saying dereferencing pointer to incomplete type. Any ideas?

Comment: @chrisaycock: Nonsense. In the original code, `cur` certainly is a pointer, and certainly is on the stack (i.e., has `auto` storage class).

Comment: @Gabe Don't use the arrow (->), just stick to the dot (.) instead.

Comment: @Gabe Mixed up my example code, in which cur is no longer a pointer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `cur` is a **pointer** of type timeval. You need to have a timeval **variable** and pass it's address to the function. Something like:

```
struct timeval cur;
do_gettimeofday(&cur);
```

You also need

```
#include<linux/time.h>
```

which has the definition of the struct timeval and declaration of the function `do_gettimeofday`.

Alternatively you can use the `gettimeofday` function from `sys/time.h`.

[**Working link**](http://www.ideone.com/5vo2s)

Comment: That function is in `<linux/time.h>`, and the error is because he's trying to access a member of a pointer.

Comment: The answer is still misleading about `do_gettimeofday`.  As I said, it's a function declared in `<linux/time.h>`, and that header also defines `struct timeval`.

Comment: If you can take a look at my next post, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include sys/time.h instead of time.h, struct timeval is defined in /usr/include/sys/time.h and not in /usr/include/time.h.

Comment: In my case I was getting storage size of "variable" isn't known until i switched from including time.h to sys/time.h. Thank you very much for your addition.